# Drupal Views Inject Content

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a View setup in Drupal that is a list of products. Each product has an associated location and all of the locations in a view are displayed in a map that is on the bottom of the page.

What I'd like to do is to bring the map "INTO" the view so that it works better with the flow of the page. Here's the layout:

Table

```
 col col map map
 col col map map
 col col col col
 col col col col
```

What would be the best way of integrating the map with the table?

Comment: GMap Module: provides the GMap API, integration with Views and Location, and GMap macros

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap). There is also a [great screen cast](http://www.drupaltherapy.com/gmap) that shows how to use it. You can also take a look into the [OpenLayers module](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) to add maps into nodes.

Comment: My question wasn't how to add a map to the page...it's how to add a map WITHIN the content of a view. My map is already in a block and I can put it anywhere...but not sure how to flow a view around it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a DIV class for each row using Grid format. This assigned a different value for each field. I then moved those pieces to a different region and replaced them with my map.